# Lipschitz continuity of a certain function

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{P_1,\cdots,P_n\}$ be a collection of point-sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Given a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we define the following (convex) function

$F_z(x) = \sum_{i\in[n]}\max_{p\in P_i}\Vert x-p\Vert^z$, where $z\in\{1,2\}$.

It is easy to see that $\vert F_1(x) - F_1(y)\vert \leq n\Vert x-y\Vert$. This follows from the triangle inequality. **My question is that if there is a similar relation for $F_2(\cdot)$**, i.e. whether $\exists$ some paramter $K>0$, which is independent of $x$ and $y$ s.t $\vert F_2(x) - F_2(y)\vert \leq K\Vert x-y\Vert^2$. Note that triangle inequality does not hold in this case, although approximate triangle inequality does exists, i.e $\Vert x-y\Vert^2 \leq 2(\Vert x-z\Vert^2 + \Vert z-y\Vert^2)$.

The following two inequalities are well known

1. $\vert \Vert p-c\Vert^2 - \Vert q-c\Vert^2\vert \leq \epsilon\Vert p-c\Vert^2 + (1+1/\epsilon)\Vert p-q\Vert^2$, for any $\epsilon >0$
2. $2\langle w-v,u-v\rangle  = \Vert w-v\Vert^2 - \Vert w-u\Vert^2 + \Vert u-v\Vert^2 \geq \Vert w-v\Vert^2 - \Vert w-u\Vert^2 $.

Using point 1, it is not hard to derive the following bound

$\vert F_2(x) - F_2(y)\vert \leq (1+1/\epsilon)n\Vert x-y\Vert^2 + \epsilon.F_2(x)$

Using point 2 along with [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz,vector%20algebra%20and%20other%20areas.), one can derive the following bound

$F_2(x) - F_2(y) \leq 2\Vert x-y\Vert\sqrt{nF_2(x)}\leq \Vert x-y\Vert^2 + nF_2(x)$.

Comment: It can't be Lipschitz on the whole space, as $\| \cdot \|^2$ is a special case of it.

Comment: @user251257, can you please elaborate. In my case $F_2(y)$ is always the global optimum.

Comment: consider $n=1$ and $P_1 = \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @user251257 , ok I get it. In general $a^2 -b^2$ can not be upper bounded by $(a-b)^2$